Oracle dataguard is not working properly because default value
I created a table with default values。
CREATE TABLE "TEST"."AA" (
  "COL1" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  "cretime" TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP
).

I inserted a piece of data into PRIMARY_ROLE database。
INSERT INTO "AA"("COL1", "cretime") VALUES ('2', TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-06-03 15:18:18.028', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF3'))
> Affected rows: 1
> 时间: 0.029s

but STANDBY_ROLE database did not have the data, and a few moment later ,PRIMARY_ROLE database did not have the data too.
I tried insert on another table without default value,it is successful.
I want to know the reason of this problem.
whether the default value cause this problem.

"a few moment later ,PRIMARY_ROLE database did not have the data too" - that sounds like you didn't commit the data, and either explicitly or implicitly rolled back?

Standby (Data Guard) relies on archived redo logs being shipped to the remote host, it's not an instant update. And, as per @alexpoole, your transaction needs to be committed to the database first.

I think the problem is not related to transactions. Executing two consecutive SQL statements, the other one succeeded
